# Which of these filters is the best for a laser cutter project?

Tags: filter

[image: which filter]

I am building a CO2 laser cutter.  I seem to have inadvertently bought a redundant item.  Which of the two powerline filters in the attached pic should I use?  I am not an electrical engineer by any means; I bought the smaller item from a parts list provided by the seller of the plans for this machine.  Some time went by after that purchase, and then I started studying the wiring diagram that the laser-controller-module manufacturer has published... and I think that's how I ended up with the larger module on the left.

Comment: What do you want the filter to achieve electrically and with respect to EMC regulations? What sort of interference from your cutter might be present on the AC lines that you wish to remove?

Comment: Would go with the bigger one. If the AMP-rating is sufficient it can provide more "filtering".

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Based on what, it provides more filtering? Did you check the component values?

Comment: It depends what you mean by best. If you need mains inlet, use the inlet with filter. If you need filter, use the filter. Why do you think you need an extra filter at all? If you want more filtering then provide data sheets for both to know which one filters more. How much current you need, any component must be able to pass it. If you don't know what components those are then you can't use them.

Comment: @Justme It has a second choke in series. I did not check the values, but would go with the reasoning: More choke, more filtering. Otherwise it would not be there like in the smaller one. But this is "Aluminium-Foil-Head-Reasoning".